# Return result as an Array of Values Only

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following collection

```
[ { _id: 5b12a7977990062f097d03ce,
    name: 'Breakfast',
    category: 'dining' },
  { _id: 5b12a7977990062f097d03d0,
    name: 'Brunch',
    category: 'dining' },
  { _id: 5b12a7977990062f097d03d2,
    name: 'Lunch',
    category: 'dining' } ]
```

I have to collect all the `name` having `category` `dining` in a main array

I have tried this

```
       const subCategory = await SubCategory.aggregate([
          { '$match': { category: "dining" }},
          { '$group': {
            '_id': null,
            'category': { '$push': '$name' }
          }}
        ])
```

But it gives me output like this

```
[ { _id: null,
    category: 
     [ 'Breakfast',
       'Brunch',
       'Lunch' ] } ]
```

And I want output like this

```
     [ 'Breakfast',
       'Brunch',
       'Lunch' ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map()`. Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with mongoose as it returns an array, and you are better off simply using the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) `_id` than using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

```
const subCategory = (await SubCategory.aggregate([
  { '$match': { category: "dining" } },
  { '$group': { '_id': "$name" } }
])).map(({ _id }) => _id);
```

Or with [`Cursor.map()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#map) if using the underlying `Collection` from the core driver:

```
const subCategory = await SubCategory.collection.aggregate([
  { '$match': { category: "dining" } },
  { '$group': { '_id': "$name"  } }
]).map(({ _id }) => _id).toArray();
```

Much the same with `find()` if you don't want the "distinct" results:

```
const subCategory = (await Subcategory.find({ category: "dining" }))
  .map(({ name }) => name);
```

Or with the [`Cursor.map()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#map)

```
const subCategory = await Subcategory.collection.find({ category: "dining" })
  .map(({ name }) => name).toArray();
```

You can also use [`distinct()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#distinct_distinct), which basically does a variation of the aggregation process and the `map()` "under the hood" ( the "return just the field part" and not the distinct aggregation method ):

```
const subCategory = await SubCategory.distinct("name",{ category: "dining" });
```

MongoDB itself won't return anything other than a BSON Document, and a simple string is NOT a BSON Document.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.mycoll.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                category: 'dining'
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                category: {
                    $addToSet: '$name'
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $out: "temp"
        }

    ]
```

The resultset obtained upon execution of above aggregate query will be stored into a temporary collection temp

Into next stage we can execute following operation to obtain result as an array.

```
db.temp.distinct('name')
```