# How to solve 'TypeError: db.find(...).toArray is not a function' in mongodb mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query my mongodb collection so as to update a field but am facing an error when trying to use `.toArray` to loop through all the documents.

Whenever I run the code below, it shows `TypeError: meme.find(...).toArray is not a function`.

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to solve it?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoolia = require('mongoolia').default;
var algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

//meme schema
var meme = require('../app/model/meme');

const TagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tagarray: { type: String, required: true, algoliaIndex: true },
});

TagSchema.plugin(mongoolia, {
  appId: 'QQVL4GOPOL',
  apiKey: 'd93766f242500de7a13183eeeb6a7934',
  indexName: 'test1'
})

meme.find().toArray(function(memes){
   meme.update({_id: memes._id}, {$set: { objectID: memes._id.toString().slice(10).slice(0,24)}}); 
});
```

Comment: You have to check what .find() returns. You can only convert to array if the returned is a result. Check what find() returns if nothing is found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Model.find().toArray() claiming to not have .toArray() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858299/model-find-toarray-claiming-to-not-have-toarray-method)

Comment: You can check this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674201/return-result-as-an-array-of-values-only

Answer (score 1):

change `find().toArray()` to `find().fetch();`

Comment: Please explain how this fixes the problem, and why

Comment: i had exactly same error message and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466623/mongodb-foreach-vs-fetch-each, solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

i found this after a lot of try

```
 db.collection(collection).find(data, (err, res) => err ? reject(err) : res.toArray().then(x => resolve(x)))
```