# Convert the mongoose find() query result into flat array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Upon the mongoose find() query the result i am getting is:

```
[
   {
      "services":[
         {
            "location":[
               17.4374614,
               78.4482878
            ]
         },
         {
            "location":[
               17.4020637,
               78.48400519999996
            ]
         },
         {
            "location":[
               17.387031788259197,
               78.47838450137715
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Is there any way to extract the output in such a way that i want an array of only location values such as:-

```
[
    '17.4374614',
    '78.4482878',
    '17.4020637',
    '78.48400519999996',
    '17.387031788259197',
    '78.47838450137715'
]
```

Edit: I am aware that map method does the job, but i am not able to find a workaround of implementing the map method for the above query.

My schema:

```
var serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  location:[{type: Number}]

})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return result as an Array of Values Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674201/return-result-as-an-array-of-values-only)

Answer (score 0):

I used for-of loop and map function to achieve the result you need

```
var your_output =[
                   {
                      "services":[
                         {
                            "location":[
                               17.4374614,
                               78.4482878
                            ]
                         },
                         {
                            "location":[
                               17.4020637,
                               78.48400519999996
                            ]
                         },
                         {
                            "location":[
                               17.387031788259197,
                               78.47838450137715
                            ]
                         }
                      ]
                   }
                ]

var location_array = []
   for (var services of output[0].services) {
      for(var loc of services.location){
         location_array.push(loc)
      }
   }
location_array.map(String)
```